# How can I have a loading icon appear before an iframe is comepletely loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, load

I'm trying to figure out how to show a loading icon and switch to the iFrame once it's loaded. Is there some function like `onclick` or something?

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is to have a div appear saying "Loading..." and once the iFrame completely loads the page show the iframe. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the initial frame content as just an animated gif for a loading icon and then load the actual document, separately, in an AJAX call.  When the remote call completes it would replace the contents of the appropriate DOM element (e.g `document.body`) with the fetched page.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this by setting an animated gif (from [Ajaxload](http://www.ajaxload.info/)) on the iframe container's background image. The only consideration to take is that the iframe body should set a background color.

Whilst the iframe is loading, its background should be transparent and the icon should show through.