# show loading icon while loading video javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load a video onclick a image in my web page. For that i used the following code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$('a.newID').click(function(){ 

$('#newID').html('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TJ2X4dFhAC0?autoplay=1"  frameborder="0" class="slide" allowtransparency="true" style="width:512px; height:288px;" id="ifm" title=""></iframe>');

});
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

The html code:

```
<a href="#" title="" id="newID"><span class="play_icon"><img src="img/play_overON.png" alt=""></span>
    <img src="images/slider1.jpg" alt="" class="slide" />
    </a>
```

If i click the image the image will be replaced by the iframe video. What i need is to `display a loading icon` until the `video` is `loading`. How to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500515/how-can-i-have-a-loading-icon-appear-before-an-iframe-is-comepletely-loaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add following css properties in your `click` function:

```
 #newID {background-image:url(http://mysite/myloadingimage.gif)}
```

You will also need to add css property `display:inline-block;` to #newID, if the display is `inline` (default).

Replace `http://mysite/myloadingimage.gif` with actual loading image. Use animated gif for the nice loading effect.

Loading image needs to be centered using css background property. This may depend on size of image.

Comment: Really sorry, I missed seeing that you are replacing the image in next statement. Give me 2 minutes, I will give you a solution.

Comment: Please let me know the result. If it is still not working please setup a fiddle using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry, I overlooked the code on first glance.